# Calling ASP.NET Web Api to do some actions

Tags: wcf

I am creating a Web Api integrates with SignalR.

I want to create a Web Api method that will receive a string/object as parameter (from an winform exe) and broadcast it to all the SignalR clients.

I know that Web Api uses HTTP requests like `PUT` `DELETE` `POST` `GET`. All of these requests are database related, i.e. `PUT` for Update, `DELETE` for Delete, `POST` for Insert, `GET` for Select.

In this case, which HTTP request should I use?

```
public void BroadcastToClients() {}
```

Or should I consider WCF instead of Web Api?

Answer (score 0):

People tend to get all up-tight about "pure" REST vs just getting something to work.  For every cited reference that argues for one scheme, you can find another that is the opposite.

My very personal opinion is that POST is when something new is to be created, and PUT when an entity is to be updated.

I think the important thing is to just be **consistent**.